# Accessing Core Model from Controller Not Working

Tags: sapui5

I have added a named model in Component.js. I can access model with its name from any view but I want to access this model from one of the controllers which is not working for me.

`sap.ui.core.getModel("modelName")` is not working and `sap.ui.getCore().getModel("modelName")` is also not working.

How to refer its containing Component and a named model from a controller?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If the model was registered using the manifest path sap.ui5->models it seems to be available in the controllers only by

```
  this.getOwnerComponent().getModel(modelName);
```

I have experienced this especially for the i18n model.

Answer (score 10):

Please use `this.getView().getModel(name)` in your controller. To address the issue that models created in/from the Component are not yet ready in `onInit` I added a `getModel` method in my base controller:

```
getModel : function(name) {
    return this.getView().getModel(name) || this.getOwnerComponent().getModel(name);
}
```