# How to disable V2 OData $batch request by default in UI5?

Tags: odata, sapui5

I made a Master-Detail application in Web IDE with SAPUI5.

I connected my application to an OData service (V2). The connection parameters have been stored in `manifest.json`.

I want to prevent my UI5 application from using `$batch` requests.

I know how to use the following code to disable batch request for a particular request:

```js
var oDataModel = this.getModel(); // sap.ui.model.odata.v2.ODataModel
oDataModel.setUseBatch(false);
```

But the problem is that I can not use this in `onInit` function.

Can I set some parameter in `manifest.json` to disable batch request in general and even when the program is loading it does not use `$batch`?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You should be able to add parameter `useBatch` to the settings of your model. According to the [documentation](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/topic/be0cf40f61184b358b5faedaec98b2da) (section `/sap.ui5/models`) these settings will be passed to the constructor.

```json
{
  "sap.ui5": {
    "models": {
      "yourV2ODataModel": {
        "dataSource": "yourDataSource",
        "settings": {
          "useBatch": false
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The availability of component models in `onInit` has been discussed here several [times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35100650/accessing-model-from-controller-sapui5/35102286#35102286). See the application [init](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/topic/d2f58695fce3476f92fdfc07c9e8f7c6) process to see why they are not available.

Answer (score 0):

Well you could to it in the `onInit` function. But like this:

```
var oDataModel = this.getOwnerComponent().getModel();

oDataModel.setUseBatch(false);
```

Comment: hi, setting properties of a model that is defined in manifest.json is not considered good idea. imagine the model being replaced by a mockservers model or what not. 

the correct answer is already given, and is to set the models settings in the manifest.json

Answer (score 0):

Go to Component.js

on its "init" method:

```
this.getModel("yourDesiredModel").setUseBatch(false)
```