# Disable $batch requests for OData v4 in Fiori project?

Tags: odata, sapui5, sap-fiori

I am trying out SAP Business Studio Trial for consuming Odata service V4 (which does not support batch processing) and I have created a trial account Created dev space for that.

After that I have created *New Project(Project From Template) - > SAP Fiori Application -> Floorplan - List Report Object Page -> Provided OData Service Details.-> Selected Entity* and created app.

As per documentation I changed `manifest.json` and added `groupid` as `$direct`, I have not made any other changes to the project.

e.g.

```
{
"models": {
            "i18n": {
                "type": "sap.ui.model.resource.ResourceModel",
                "uri": "i18n/i18n.properties"
            },
            "": {
                "dataSource": "mainService",
                "preload": true,
                "settings": {
                    "synchronizationMode": "None",
                    "operationMode": "Server",
                    "autoExpandSelect": true,
                    "earlyRequests": true,
                    "groupId":"$direct"
                }
            }
        }
}
```

still when I start app batch requests are sent.

What more configuration is required to disable the batch requests?

Project structure from Web IDE

[image]

Logs:

```
info server:ux-proxy /resources/sap/ui/base/Metadata-dbg.js
info server:ux-proxy /resources/sap/ui/mdc/Table-dbg.js
info server:ux-proxy /resources/sap/ui/core/Element-dbg.js
info server:ux-proxy /resources/sap/ui/base/DataType-dbg.js
info server:ux-proxy /resources/sap/ui/mdc/mixin/FilterIntegrationMixin-dbg.js
info server:ux-proxy /resources/sap/ui/core/IntervalTrigger-dbg.js
info server:ux-proxy /resources/sap/ui/mdc/filterbar/FilterBarBase-dbg.js
info server:ux-proxy /resources/sap/ui/fl/manifest.json
info server:ux-proxy /resources/sap/ui/table/manifest.json
info server:ux-proxy /resources/sap/fe/templates/manifest.json
info server:ux-proxy Rewrite path /AG/API/services/E/1.0.0/$batch > /AG/API/services/E/1.0.0/$batch
info server:ux-proxy Rewrite path /AG/API/services/E/1.0.0/$batch > /AG/API/services/E/1.0.0/$batch
```

Comment: [How to disable Odata Batch request by default in SAPUI5?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41996224/5550071)

Comment: that options seems to be for odata v2 models

Comment: Can you please edit your question with the a picture of the developer console logs of the batch requests?

Comment: Also check how you define your tables and lists, it could contain a snippet like
`<Table
       id="tableItems"
       items="{
        path: '/tableItems',
        parameters: {
         $$updateGroupId : 'tableItemGroup'
        }
       }"......`

Comment: attached logs. @draysams I could not find tale snippet